# What happens to a judgment when one of the parties dies?

Tags: united-states, civil-judgment, enforcing-judgment

A sues B, wins a judgment, and can't collect because B has no money. A dies. Is B off the hook?

B dies first. Does A have a claim against B's estate?

Comment: You may see rule 25 of the Federal Rules of Civil Procedure regarding the second question you raised.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the estate takes over. If A dies, then B owes the money to A's estate. If B dies, then B's estate owes the money to A.

If B's estate is empty, then the debt is retired, because a debt cannot be inherited.

Comment: More precisely, A becomes an unsecured creditor of B's estate and receives whatever dividend is paid by the estate in bankruptcy.